# ExtJS Modern - column.getCell is not a function

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS 6.2.0.981 Modern application. I am trying to add a "textfield" into a grid cell but I get the following error:

```
column.getCell is not a function
```

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rbt) is the fiddle

I checked the [DOCS](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.grid.cell.Widget.html) for the "widgetcell" component and it states: 
This class is used for Ext.grid.Grid cells that contain a child Ext.Component or Ext.Widget. This cell type is typically used by specifying Ext.grid.column.Widget column type.

But Ext.grid.column.Widget seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `widgetcell` config into `cell`

```
columns: [{
    text: "Column 1",
    dataIndex: "COL1",
    flex: 1,
    cell: {
        xtype: "widgetcell",
        widget: {
            xtype: "textfield",
            label: "Col 1 Widget"
        }
    }

}]
```